# Error while making signed apk after enabling the Proguard in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, andengine

**Error while making signed apk after enabling the Proguard  in Android Studio.**

> Warning:org.andengine.engine.camera.hud.controls.AnalogOnScreenControl:
>   can't find referenced method 'float cos(float)' in library class
>   android.util.FloatMath
>       Warning:org.andengine.engine.camera.hud.controls.AnalogOnScreenControl:
>   can't find referenced method 'float sin(float)' in library class
>   android.util.FloatMath
>       Warning:org.andengine.entity.modifier.PathModifier$Path: can't find referenced method 'float sqrt(float)' in library class
>   android.util.FloatMath
>       Warning:org.andengine.entity.particle.ParticleSystem: can't find referenced method 'float floor(float)' in library class
>   android.util.FloatMath
>       Warning:org.andengine.entity.particle.emitter.CircleOutlineParticleEmitter:
>   can't find referenced method 'float cos(float)' in library class
>   android.util.FloatMath
>       Warning:org.andengine.entity.particle.emitter.CircleOutlineParticleEmitter:
>   can't find referenced method 'float sin(float)' in library class
>   android.util.FloatMath
>       Warning:org.andengine.entity.particle.emitter.CircleParticleEmitter:
>   can't find referenced method 'float cos(float)' in library class
>   android.util.FloatMath
>       Warning:org.andengine.entity.particle.emitter.CircleParticleEmitter:
>   can't find referenced method 'float sin(float)' in library class
>   android.util.FloatMath
>       Warning:org.andengine.opengl.font.StrokeFont: can't find referenced method 'float floor(float)' in library class
>   android.util.FloatMath
>       Warning:org.andengine.util.adt.transformation.Transformation: can't find referenced method 'float sin(float)' in library class
>   android.util.FloatMath
>       Warning:org.andengine.util.adt.transformation.Transformation: can't find referenced method 'float cos(float)' in library class
>   android.util.FloatMath
>       Warning:org.andengine.util.algorithm.path.astar.EuclideanHeuristic:
>   can't find referenced method 'float sqrt(float)' in library class
>   android.util.FloatMath
>       Warning:org.andengine.util.math.MathUtils: can't find referenced method 'float ceil(float)' in library class android.util.FloatMath
>       Warning:org.andengine.util.math.MathUtils: can't find referenced method 'float sin(float)' in library class android.util.FloatMath
>       Warning:org.andengine.util.math.MathUtils: can't find referenced method 'float cos(float)' in library class android.util.FloatMath
>       Warning:org.andengine.util.math.MathUtils: can't find referenced method 'float sqrt(float)' in library class android.util.FloatMath
>       Warning:org.andengine.util.modifier.ease.EaseCircularIn: can't find referenced method 'float sqrt(float)' in library class
>   android.util.FloatMath
>       Warning:org.andengine.util.modifier.ease.EaseCircularOut: can't find referenced method 'float sqrt(float)' in library class
>   android.util.FloatMath
>       Warning:org.andengine.util.modifier.ease.EaseElasticIn: can't find referenced method 'float sin(float)' in library class
>   android.util.FloatMath
>       Warning:org.andengine.util.modifier.ease.EaseElasticOut: can't find referenced method 'float sin(float)' in library class
>   android.util.FloatMath
>       Warning:org.andengine.util.modifier.ease.EaseSineIn: can't find referenced method 'float cos(float)' in library class
>   android.util.FloatMath
>       Warning:org.andengine.util.modifier.ease.EaseSineInOut: can't find referenced method 'float cos(float)' in library class
>   android.util.FloatMath
>       Warning:org.andengine.util.modifier.ease.EaseSineOut: can't find referenced method 'float sin(float)' in library class
>   android.util.FloatMath``

Comment: How does Your proguard's config files looks like?

Comment: I think proguard stripped out those methods from that library while it is being used by it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Android docs on FloatMath:

> This class was deprecated in API level 22.
>
> Use Math instead.

It seems that one of your dependencies was built for an older Android SDK than your target SDK level.

Try adding:
`-keep public class android.util.FloatMath`
to your proguard rules.